# Pass Navigation Parameter to Nav or Layout component in blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

On the Blazor (server side) app, I have a nested layout. When we go to the page in the nested layout, i have the nav for navigating to other pages. The landing page's url is /items/3 where 3 is {id:int}. Now to navigate to other pages, I need to pass this id to the Nav/Layout component - so that then i can use the id on the other s. How to pass this id to the Nav or Layout component?

Tried putting the [Parameter] tag on the Nav or Layout component but the param is not populated.

Comment: Have a look at this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57811557/blazor-access-parameter-from-layout/57812801#57812801

Comment: If anyone has this question, look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65202371/7734384

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can pass a value from a component to your layout component. No such feature exist... But, I guess you can employ some hacking. However, you should use IUriHelper to navigate to another page, something like this:

```
@inject Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Services.IUriHelper UriHelper

<button onclick=@Navigate>Click me to navigate to another page</button>


@functions {
    private void Navigate()
    {
        UriHelper.NavigateTo("/hello-world");
    }
}
```

Edit:
As I've written above, there is no way to pass a parameter from a child component to a parent component. You should adjust your app to the features, behaviors and limitations provided by Blazor. Below is a link to an issue in Github, which you can read and understand the mechanism of passing parameters. There's also a comment by Steve Anderson in which he suggests how you can hack around this: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/857

Hope this helps...

Comment: Well, the issue is I need the id param on the Nav component which is referred on the landing page. The landing page has the id but how to pass it to the Nav component? Don't see how this solution will solve it?

Comment: The github link you provided is spot on. Thats the issue I am facing. Looks like we need to have a work around. Thank you!