# Blazor: Access parameter from layout

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

How can I access a page's route parameter from the layout?

I have a page that accepts a route parameter like the following:

```
@page /my-page/{Slug}
```

I am needing to access the value of `Slug` when rendering markup in the shared layout.

I have tried implementing `OnParametersSet` in the layout file like the following, but the value is not set.  It's only assigned at the page level.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <NavMenu />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4">
            @this.Slug   <<<<------ display the parameter
    </div>

    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // Slug is always null :-/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After some muddling around, I have come up with the following solution.  It can probably all be done in the `.razor` files, but I implemented some of the mess in the "code-behind" files to hide what seems to be a kludge.

In the Layout instance, if you override `OnParametersSet`, and drill into `Body.Target` you'll find the `RouteData`, containing the route parameter(s).  You can then propagate these value(s) to the child components in the layout.

**Page with a "Slug" parameter we want to make available to the Layout**

```
@page "/mypage/{Slug}"
```

**Layout .razor file**

```
@inherits Components.MyLayoutBase

<div class="sidebar">
    <!-- Pass the Slug property to the NavMenu's Parameter -->
    <MyNavMenu Slug="@Slug" />
</div>

<div class="main">
    <div class="top-row px-4"></div>    
    <div class="content px-4">
        @Body
    </div>
</div>
```

**Layout code behind**

```cs
public class MyLayoutBase : LayoutComponentBase
{
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        // pull out the "Slug" parameter from the route data
        object slug = null;
        if ((this.Body.Target as RouteView)?.RouteData.RouteValues?.TryGetValue("Slug", out slug) == true)
        {
            Slug = slug?.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**Navigation Menu**

```
<div class="top-row pl-4 navbar navbar-dark">
</div>

<div class="@NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@($"/some-page/{Slug}/foo")">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Foo
            </NavLink>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@($"/some-page/{Slug}/bar")">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Bar
            </NavLink>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

@code {

    [Parameter]
    public string Slug { get; set; }

    bool collapseNavMenu = true;

    string NavMenuCssClass => collapseNavMenu ? "collapse" : null;

    string setupUrl = string.Empty;

    void ToggleNavMenu()
    {
        collapseNavMenu = !collapseNavMenu;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bravo, I was thinking of suggesting you to create a service that exposes a notify property changed from the component page's OnInitializedAsync method, and passes the route parameter to Mainlayout component. I wonder what the Blazor team has to say about your solution. Delegate.Target is a quite obscure property...

Comment: this worked for me. I like the neatness of tocqueville's answer but I was having problems with concurrency using that, whereas this works fine

Answer (score 27):

You can make the RouteData available to all your components via CascadingParameters. In your App.razor, do this:

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <CascadingValue Value="@routeData">
            <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MyLayout)" />
        </CascadingValue>
    </Found>
</Router>
```

Then, in all components where you need the RouteData, simply add:

```
@code
{
    [CascadingParameter]
    RouteData RouteData { get; set; }
}
```

The value will be automatically populated.

Comment: tocqueville seems like @dobestar from the comment above, had issues with concurrency. Are you having problems with your implementation? Are you using it in production? Let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The answer above didn't address nested layouts. In those situations I got the following to work. The cascading parameter approach also has some underlying issues: [Blazor WASM - Navigation away from Layout using RouteData creates duplicate components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716550/blazor-wasm-navigation-away-from-layout-using-routedata-creates-duplicate-comp/70758615#70758615)

```
public static bool TryGetRouteData(this Delegate renderFragment, out RouteData routeData)
{
    routeData = null;

    if (renderFragment?.Target is RouteView routeView)
    {
        routeData = routeView.RouteData;
    }
    else if (renderFragment?.Target is object target)
    {
        // the target may be a CompilerGenerated class
        var bodyField = target.GetType().GetField("bodyParam");

        if (bodyField is not null)
        {
            var value = bodyField.GetValue(target);

            if (value is Delegate childDel)
            {
                TryGetRouteData(childDel, out routeData);
            }
        }
    }

    return routeData is not null;
}
```

Then in the layout/component class:

```
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
   if (Body?.TryGetRouteData(out var routeData) == true)
   {
       // stuff here
    }
}
```