# How do I interact with a Page from a PageLayout?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I am building my first Server-side Blazor app and using the MudBlazor component set as well as the [MudBlazor Admin UI layout](https://github.com/Garderoben/MudBlazor.Templates/tree/master/MudBlazor.Template.AdminDashboard/AdminDashboard.Server).

One of the features of the layout is that it has a nice breadcrumb component, which they have positioned in the [`MainLayout.razor` Page Layout](https://github.com/Garderoben/MudBlazor.Templates/blob/master/MudBlazor.Template.AdminDashboard/AdminDashboard.Server/Shared/MainLayout.razor), as follows;

```
<MudBreadcrumbs Items="_items"></MudBreadcrumbs>
@Body

@code {
    private List<BreadcrumbItem> _items = new List<BreadcrumbItem>
    {
        new BreadcrumbItem("Personal", href: "#"),
        new BreadcrumbItem("Dashboard", href: "/personal/dashboard"),
    };
}
```

As you can see, the `MudBreadcrumbs` component populates with items from the `_items` method, and both are located in the PageLayout's `MainLayout.razor` file.

I can see the page content is referenced and rendered at the `@Body` placeholder. So far I have about 15 pages and I'd like to use the breadcrumbs to show each current page's correct details, which means that each page needs to define its own `_items` collection.

How do I create the `_items` collection at the Page level, and make it accessible to the `MudBreadcrumbs` component in the PageLayout?

### Update

I eventually came across this SO question, which turns out to be essentially identical [and is funnier].
[How can I modify the layout from a blazor page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64473844/how-can-i-modify-the-layout-from-a-blazor-page)

It has a workable solution which is thoroughly explained- however I'm leaving this question open in case there is a more obvious and straightforward approach to communications from a Page to a Page Layout in Blazor.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I interact with a Page from a PageLayout?

Use controller for per page. In Layout page, use variables, it will be controlled from Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the answer in the post you linked to in your update but a little different + full working solution.

- I will be using a Cascading Value with an object that will call an action when whatever you want is changed.
- I will only be using a string but this does work with any other data types/objects.
- Also note I am using @bind-value for the input so it will only fire an event on change and not on input.

In MainLayout.razor or any parent container (in my case Index.razor):

```
@page "/"
@implements IDisposable

<h1>@container.UserInput</h1>
<input @bind-value="container.UserInput" />

<CascadingValue Value="container">
    <CascadingTest></CascadingTest>
</CascadingValue>

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
    testingClass.OnChange += StateHasChanged;
    }

    public YourContainer container= new();


    public void Dispose()
    {
        testingClass.OnChange -= StateHasChanged;
    }
```

The YourContainer class:

```
public class YourContainer 
{
    private string userInput= "default";
    public string UserInput
    {
        get => this.userInput;
        set
        {
            if (this.userInput == value) return;
            this.userInput= value;
            this.Changed();
        }
    }

    public event Action OnChange;

    public void Changed() => OnChange?.Invoke();
}
```

Lastly, the child component(s):

```
<label>@containerName.UserInput</label>
<input @bind-value="containerName.UserInput"/>

@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    YourContainer containerName{ get; set; }
}
```