# Blazor Webassembly lifecycle events called twice after NavigationManager.NavigateTo

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

On the load of a page (Blazor WebAssembly - NOT server), I do this:

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Initialised");
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

On first load, this is called once.  After I call:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/anotherpage");
```

With the same OnInitializedAsync code above - it is called twice on that page.  Making it really difficult to only load data from an API once.

I have read a lot about lifecycle events like OnInitializedAsync being called twice when the render mode for Blazor is set to ServerPreRendered - however this is a wasm project, and so there is no prerendering, and I'm stumped

**Update:
Further investigation has lead to the page layout actually being the culprit (as described in this bug: github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20637).  This question also describes it - but leaving this question here incase someone has the same issue I did**

Comment: How do you call `NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/anotherpage");`?  What does anotherpage look like?  `OnInitialized{Async}` is only ever called once on a page load (unless you manually code it otherwise).  On Server the page is loaded twice - once on pre-render and once on the main load.  `OnInitialized{Async}` is called once on each load.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis that's as I'd expected it to be, but it's definitely firing twice.  The /anotherpage looks the same, it has 

protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Initialised");
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}

which happens twice

Comment: Definitely, changing Layout is causing this, I was just implementing a Layout change and stumble on it today, this answer lead me to the right problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code in my side and here what I've found:

- You should have `await base.OnInitializedAsync();` instead of `return base.OnInitializedAsync();` -> using your version does not let me to build.
- I've created the following Blazor page:
- 

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

<button @onclick="OnClick">CLICK</button>

@code {

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initialised");
        await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    public void OnClick()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint in the `OnInitializedAsync` method. It is hitten on the loading of the page, but not when I clicked on the button. So I assume you do this call **outside** the page with this issue. So we'll need this part too, because I've tried this solution too (button and call in another page), same result.

Comment: Ah sorry - the OnInitializedAsync that's double firing is on the next page (in your case there /fetchdata), which I've just set up with the same Console.WriteLine as abov

Comment: Changing it to await base.OnInitializedAsync(); instead of return base.OnInitializedAsync();  didn't make any difference unfortunately

Comment: I am sorry Paul, I did not get your point :/ So you have the first page, where you have this mechanics of redirection, to the other page where you have the OnInit(...) that is fired twice, right?

Comment: The proposed change makes no difference because the original returns a task to the async Component handler method which it awaits and the answer awaits the task itself before returning a completed task.  Subtly different, but the same result.

Comment: I've just found what's causing it - apparently a good nights sleep helps the googling!  It's because the layout is changing between them.  Once I worked that out, I found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70716550/blazor-wasm-navigation-away-from-layout-using-routedata-creates-duplicate-comp/70758615#70758615

and the bug reported here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/20637

Comment: Wow thanks @Paul for this information. I did not know about this bug and I hope it will be fixed asap. Maybe you can have a workaround using the "override void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)" method, with a (if firstRender). I can provide you a more precise example with an answer if you want to :) (maybe it will not work as well but it could be worth to try)

Comment: @Paul - as per my answer below, you had more in your UI that you put in your question.  If you look at the quoted SO question you'll see my answer and the comment - "There's no fix because it's not really a bug. It's edge condition behaviour: You're doing something unexpected."

Comment: @enet He wants to say that he uses two different layouts for the pages. Page 1 with "@layout Layout1" and page 2 with "@layout Layout2"

Comment: Don't hold your breath.  I don't think the Blazor team are classifying it as a bug.  It's an open (dormant) issue that I suspect will get closed.

Comment: @enet My comments appear to have been deleted... What on earth would be the benefit of that??  It's an obscure problem, that I now known is an actual bug - I didn't ask the question and then completely stop working on the problem, and when I found the problem I updated the question.  Now I know the question isn't right, I tried to delete but it's been answered so I can't.  I've no idea why you've decided that something sinister is happening here, but it's really not

Answer (score 0):

This is my test setup to try and emulate your problem.  As I expected, `OnInitialized` is only run once per page load.  Therefore there must be something else on your pages that is causing the problem. What extra do you have on your pages?

##### First.razor

```
@page "/First"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@using System.Text

<div>
    <button @onclick=this.ClickMe> Click Me </button>
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <pre>
        @sb.ToString()
    </pre>
</div>
@code {
    private Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var message = $"OnInitialized on Component {this.Id.ToString().Substring(32)} ran at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        sb.AppendLine(message);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void ClickMe(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/Second");
    }
}
```

##### Second.razor

```
@page "/Second"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager
@using System.Text

<div>
    <button @onclick=this.ClickMe> Click Me </button>
</div>

<div class="m-2">
    <pre>
        @sb.ToString();
    </pre>
</div>
@code {
    private Guid Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    private StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var message = $"OnInitialized on Component {this.Id.ToString().Substring(32)} ran at {DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()}";
        Console.WriteLine(message);
        sb.AppendLine(message);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }

    private void ClickMe(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.NavManager.NavigateTo("/First");
    }
}
```

And the results in the console:

[image]