# How to pass a value from a page to the layout in Blazor?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have a layout (`MainLayout.razor`), and it has a flag called `ShowFooter`. On some pages, I want to be able to set that flag to `true`, and on some others to `false`.

I haven't been able to find any clear instructions on how a page (i.e. a component with a route) can communicate with its layout. How could/should this be done in Blazor?

**Note:** You might suggest creating 2 layouts, one with and one without the footer, but that wouldn't really solve my problem, I want to be able to show and hide the footer at different times on the same page. Plus, this is just one scenario where there is a need to communicate between the layout and the page. There are also countless others, to which such workarounds might not even be applicable.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The simplest way to do that is to define a public Boolean property named ShowFooter in the MainLaout component, as follows:

```
public bool ShowFooter {get; set;}
```

And to cascade a reference to MainLaout component to given components, by wrapping the markup within a `CascadingValue` component whose Value attribute is set to `this`, like this:

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase


<CascadingValue Value="this">
     <div class="sidebar">
        <NavMenu />
    </div>
    <div class="main">
         <div class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </div>
    </div>
</CascadingValue>
@code
{
    public bool ShowFooter {get; set;}

     protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
      // Put here code that checks the value of ShowFooter and acts in 
      // accordance with your dear wishes

     }
}
```

Usage in Index.razor

```
@code{
     // Gets a reference to the MainLayout component
    [CascadingParameter]
    public MainLayout Layout { get; set; } 

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Layout.ShowFooter= true;
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is clever. But between this and the `AppState` pattern that Steve Sanderson mentions [here](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/16009#issuecomment-427831659), which approach would you say is better? Would you say this is hackier?

Comment: There are a couple of ways to do that. Look for my answers in stackoverflow, it all depends on what you want to do. No this is not a more hacky way to do that. That is definitely the way to do that. The way Steve Sanderson mention s is the hacky way. It was written in the early days of Blazor development, when Blazor did not have the current capabilities and supporting built-in components. Do it like this.

Comment: Note: The AppState pattern is handling the state of components as a whole..

Comment: Okay. I'll use this then! Thanks. One last question and I'll mark your answer as accepted: Now that we're doing this, we might as well have public `ElementReference` properties on `MainLayout`: Say I have a `Toast` component in `MainLayout`, it exposes methods like `Show()` and `Hide()`, what do think about declaring a public property of type `ElementReference` in `MainLayout` that references that `Toast` component, and then in other components I can access that toast component and do things like `Layout.Toast.Show()`. Do you think that's a reasonable approach or it's terrible perhaps?!

Comment: Apparently the layout doesn't re-render when I change the public properties in a component even when I call the `StateHasChanged()` method. Is that true?

Comment: ElementReference refers to Html elements, not to C# objects. It is not used in C# code. It is passed to JavaScript functions. Perhaps you meant object reference, in which case you can capture a reference to a component (a class, right), and pass it to the MainLayout component the same way you pass a boolean value to the MainLayout.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. BTW, again, as I said changing the public properties of layout in other components on UI events, for example, doesn't appear to re-render the layout. Is that a limitation of this approach? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No "limitation of this approach". Rest assured that even Steve Anderson would have suggested you to code like this. You need the following: InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged()); Note: I'm going to post in a new answer a simple program that can be useful to you. Copy and run the code. Type text in the text box which is situated in the Index component, and you'll see the input text in the header of the MainLayout. Copy the code as I'm going to delete it soon.

Comment: Haha! Right! Thanks for the help, I appreciate it very much! (I copied and pasted the code you could delete that answer)

Comment: Or, you could have left it for others to also benefit.

Comment: I also having trouble updating the prop value. Where to place ```InvokeAsync(() => StateHasChanged())``` command? Tried placing it inside child right after setting the layout prop but that didn't work.

Comment: Wow, I feel like I **almost** had the answer to my question....

Comment: For anyone else coming across this and trying to figure how to get the prop value to update. You need to call StateHasChanged() in the parent component to ensure the parent and child components are re-rendered. This means you will need to expose a method on the parent to update the property and call StateHasChanged, rather then directly updating the parent property.

Answer (score 7):

There are a few ways to do it:

1. The ugliest: If you have two templates you can simply select the template you want to use with the following on the top of the page/component:

   @layout NoFooterLayoutName
2. Use cascading value in the template ( What I would recommend for your scenerio):

> ```
> <CascadingValue Value="Footer">
>     <Child />
> </CascadingValue>
> ```

Example fiddle:
https://blazorfiddle.com/s/05spcuyk

And Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0

3. Create a State service and add it to startup as scoped. The state service with footer bool variable, and can then be injected into pages/components and variable used:

In startup.cs ConfigureService method:

```
services.AddScoped<AppState>();
```

Create AppState.cs class somewhere in your project (ideally a Services folder):

```
public class AppState 
{
   public bool ShowFooter { get; set; }
   public event Action StateChanged;
   private void NotifyStateChanged() => StateChanged?.Invoke();
}
```

Then inject it in your page/components so you can change the ShowFooter Element and in your template you can create event handler (not sure if necessary) for that triggers StateHasChanged():

```
@inject AppState _AppState;
@implements IDisposable
.
.
.
@code{
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _appState.StateChanged += StateChanged;
    }

    public void StateChanged()
    {
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _appState.StateChanged -= StateChanged;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I like this. But can the `AppState` class be a static class, rather than registered as a singleton service? What's the advantage of having it as a singleton?

Comment: @Arad AppState class shouldn't be static, dependency injection will instantiate the class per user/request (scoped), the state classes should be designed to hold user state - and this might not be what you want it to do. If understand your problem correctly the best option might be having CascadingValue to show/hide footer (bool) on the layout component (MainLayout) so pages can set it to whatever they might like on initialized override method....

Comment: @Arad ...Keep in mind though, every page would have to set this or you would have a situation where some page will hide the footer then when navigating to another page, if footer is not reset to true it will stay hidden.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an notify service and inject this into the components.

```
public class NotifyService 
{
     public event Func<bool, Task> Notify;

     public async Task Notify(bool value) 
     {
        if (Notify is object)
        {
            await Notify.Invoke(value);
        }
     }
}
```

And then register this as a singleton (or scoped if server-side) in the DI container and inject this into your components.

Answer (score 0):

All solutions (Notify changes, Cascading Parameter...) seem ugly, unfortunately. Needless to say, we don't know what bugs will show up.

Rather, I think the clean way is to use "SectionOutlet". Basically, you want to alter the UI of the layout, right? So, declare a SectionOutlet in the Layout page and control the content of that outlet from the child page.

For instance, I created the Script Outlet in my layout page like this.

<SectionOutlet SectionId="Sections.Scripts" />

@code
{
internal static class Sections
{
internal static readonly object Scripts = new();
}
}

Then, on my page,

<SectionContent SectionId="App.Sections.Scripts">
// my script content
</SectionContent>

I am showing an example from Blazor United (.NET 8).